# global name 'find' is not defined

Tags: python

I am using a piece of code and am trying to debug it.
But something weird is happening.
In one part, I have this line:

```
vals = find(A)
```

But it gives me this error :

```
 global name 'find' is not defined
```

I thought find was like an inbuilt function in python??
Clearly I am mistaken.
But just want to check.. in case I am forgetting to include anything.

Comment: There's no built-in function called `find` in python. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: now I want to lmgtfy you

Comment: Hmm.. I thought so.. it is hard when you are looking for something like keyword "find" and instead google thinks that you are finding something.. :P stackoverflow always gets me the answers.

Comment: @Fraz, try googling `python "find function"` and `python "find method"` next time.

Comment: Why is this tagged global-variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find is a string method:

```
'python'.find('y') # gives 1
```

Comment: `y` should be a string here, not a variable: `'python'.find('y')`

Comment: @Ethan, @Infrared: The argument should be an expression which evaluates to a (Python 2) `str` or `unicode` object, preferably the same type as the object to the left of the `.`. What you are calling a "string" (actually a `str` constant) is one such expression. The "variable" (actually a name) is one such expression, provided it actually does refer to a `str` or `unicode` object`.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is:

look in this page:

http://docs.python.org/genindex.html

Why thinking to search with Google and not in an official doc ? Did you think that Python hadn't documentation ?

Comment: Keep in mind that _answers which are just links are discouraged_. You should quote from the source so the answer is useful without following the link, or post it as a comment.

Comment: Official docs are found with google.